# html page .net connection using web services error

Tags: jsonp

```js
$.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:49326/WebSite1/Service.asmx/calledfunction",
               data:{},
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp : "callback",
    jsonp: "jsonpcallback",
     crossDomain: true,
                success: function (result)
    {
    alert(result);
                 
                }
            });
```

i was getting this error 
jquery3.2.1.min.js:4GET:http://localhost:49326/WebSite1/Service.asmx/calledfunction?callback=jQuery32103652224465323135_1501578805141&_=1501578805143

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A link to your `localhost` won't help understand your issue

Comment: can i know how to call a webservice from HTML page with ajax request 
i have used the above mentioned code i was getting that error.                        "http://localhost:49326/WebSite1/Service.asmx/calledfunction"              "called function" just returns an integer value to ajax request